# POST to Bot timed out after 15s

Tags: azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework

Sometimes I am getting timeout error from my bot. Getting timeout for the first response itself.

Is there any option to increase that 15 seconds time?

Also, is there any option to skip this timeout issue?

Exception type :    Microsoft.Bot.Schema.BotTimeoutException
Failed method :     Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+d__31.MoveNext

It is bot using C# and directlinechannel.

Please let me know if you need any other information

Comment: "Getting timeout for the first response itself." << set you web app to "Always On" on Azure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem in the Bot Framework, the direct line connection will timeout in 15s and currently there is no way to suppress it, check the following thread.

https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/3220

this type of enforcement to make the bot more active and force to make faster bots.

same goes for Google's Dialog flow which timeouts at 5 seconds and Alexa Skill which timeouts at 8 seconds, so 15 second for Bot Framework is generous :P

Comment: Thanks Mumin, Is there any workaround from bot client? Like sending same message to bot automatically if it fails?

Comment: @SriramTamilarasan Sadly, but you can create your own integration layer and suppress the error messages instead of using the out of the box directline.

or creating a async task reader writer logic that will return to the user if the task is taking more that 5 seconds and say that if he wants to continue

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle this with Periodic [`refresh token`](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/11/02/optimizing-latency-bot-framework/)

```
 var credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(appID, appPassword);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => 
        {
            while (!_getTokenAsyncCancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try{
                    var token = await credentials.GetTokenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                catch(MicrosoftAppCredentials.OAuthException ex)
                {
                    Trace.TraceError(ex.message);
                }
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), _getTokenAsyncCancellation.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan, my query is not about refreshing token, as my bot is taking more time to respond it is getting timed out error. Is there any option to increase that 15 seconds time?

Also, is there any option to skip this timeout issue?